# Meteor reading data from a file stored on server

Tags: meteor

I want to show some data points on the client side, and I want to get the latitude, longitude and summary from a file stored on the server.

I have read a lot of posts saying to use papaParse using Meteor methods but I am not able to make it work.

Can you guys point me to right direction, my questions are:

1. In which folder to should I store a `.txt`, `.csv` or `.json` file in Meteor?
2. How to access it from the client and return the read data to client for display.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your static files into `private` folder on the server and get them through [`Assets`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html).

For exmaple, you have a `data.json` file in your `private` folder.

Method to get this data:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  getData() {
    return JSON.parse(Assets.getText('data.json'));
  }
});
```

You can now call this method on the client:

```js
Meteor.call('getData', function(err, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

**UPD**

Ok, how to display it.

`Meteor.call` runs async, so we will use reactivity to update our view on result.

Here is how we can display data on `ourData` template.

```html
<template name="ourData">
    <!-- Here you may want to use #each or whatever -->
    <p>{{ourData}}</p>
</template>
```

```js
Template.ourData.onCreated(function() {

  this.ourData = new ReactiveVar();

  Meteor.call('getData', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      // Putting data in reactive var
      this.ourData.set(res);
    }
  });
});

Template.ourData.helpers({
  ourData: function() {
    // Helper will automatically rerun on method res
    return Template.instance().ourData.get();
  }
});
```

`reactive-var` package required or you can also use `Session`.

Comment: how would I use the res i.e. result outside this Meteor.call function.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do with that data. Can you say? Oh, i see now you want to display it. Answer in progress.